# Angular application component not loading the local storage values after redirect

Tags: angular, redirect

In my application in sign n form I have set some values to the local storage. And I am redirecting after values set to the local storage. But the problem is redirected page is not getting that value in first redirect. But if I refresh the page using browser refresh button it take the values.

This is how I redirect

```js
if (res["returnFlag"] === 0) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal
    const userid = res["loginEmployeeId"];
    const username = res["username"];

    localStorage.setItem("userid", userid);
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);

    console.log(username);
    // console.log('signed in log val:' + localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'));

    // location.href = "dashboard";
    // this.router.navigateByUrl("dashboard");

    // this.router.navigated;
    this.router.navigate(["dashboard"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute)
```

and

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(res => {
 // here you need to call the method which you are setting up
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the data from localStorage by using the exact same key that you used to set values. Also, make sure the res contains the value. before set values to the localStorage check for null and undefined.

```
const userid = res["loginEmployeeId"];
const username = res["username"];
localStorage.setItem("userid", userid ?? '');
localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
localStorage.setItem("username", username ?? '');
```

Comment: This is the case. When loading the page the page is not initializing the values of the local storage. But if I refresh the page it is initializing

Answer (score 0):

any solved? have the same issue but in my case localStorage every return empty... inclusive when reload page...

```
 this.authService.signIn(user).subscribe({
      next: (res) =>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.user)+' sigin login component');
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.user))
        window.location.href = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/index'
      },
      error: (error)=>{
        console.log(error,'error sign');

        this.serverError=error.error.error ;
      }
    }
    )
```

***and localStorage into navigator stay empty everithing***

**Update.. this code work.. solved restarting my web browser **